# X-Keys for DAW Control

Tags: pt-quick-keys, keycommand, controller, keyboard, daw

http://www.piengineering.com/xkeys.php

Is anyone using this for executing shortcuts / key commands in your DAW? It seems like a good idea without spending $$$$ on something from Euphonix.

Any advantages / pitfalls you can think of? Is anyone using something similar?

I've also been looking for MIDI controllers with lots of buttons, but haven't had much luck finding anything (except musical keyboard controllers, which would be interesting...).

In Cubase, I can set up MIDI to control every function, but I think the advantages of programmed key commands may be better (with this thing I could do funky ones I'd probably never remember like Command-Option-Shift-1-2-3-4-5-6 = Reverse Region).  In Cubase, all functions are "key-commandable" as well.

So I'd generally use standard key commands for basic things (I programmed all the Pro Tools key commands into Cubase since I still remember all of them), and something like X-keys for things that generally don't already have a key command associated with them (though, again, I'd assign a long one I'd never use anyway like the example above).

I'm sure something like this would be useful in Pro Tools as well, possibly using that Quick   Keys app to execute mouse movements and for stacking commands as macros.  Or Logic where I believe key commands are assignable.

Thoughts?

Thanks,
fonte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually yes i used to use it. The shuttle pro one. I used it for about 3 years and loved it. But let me tell you this about it. If you get good at it and you will it will keep you from being universal on other systems. You will find that if you don't have it you want it. Getting good with the keyboard shortcuts gets your universal on all systems you might come across. I found this out after we went to Mac's and it was not supported on it. Its since been updated for mac. and I just refuse to go back. I am just as fast and good with the keyboard.

Comment: Good point.  That's why I'd plan on using standard key commands when available, and the X-keys for batch stuff (macros) and for "Audiosuite" (I'm using Cubase so there's not a word for it) tasks.

What were some of your favorite things about it?  What sorts of commands did you have set up?

Comment: @chris fonte copy paste, nudge left /right, play, stop, punch record, I actually have a pict and also might have the template still. I used it in Nuendo and there is a chance the template works in cubase too. You can pretty much set it up to do whatever you want. 

Comment: @Chris Fonte we have like 3 lying around at work collecting dust. email me ryanhdd@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

I have the shuttlePro 2.  I like it a lot.  Nuendo doesnt do scroll wheel zooming, but the SP2 can be programmed for it.